# Strange behaviour with HMAC openssl

Tags: hash, openssl, hmac

I need to execute hmac openssl, but when change a parameter I have a strange behaviour.

With these values, HMAC works properly

```
$ printf 03d4f7e460787295bb803f7f9fa3c023b3cb33623aadbea53720decfa5a4f6005800000000 |xxd -r -p | openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac `printf 71ef1c30a1a5503dd387aac85b714b779c7df8bc163b1fad66b1d51c94cd221e|xxd -r -p` | awk '{print $2}'
71af33b003e7e8033fcec8ad2ef46ee22b6518ae072fae24708201542d1b01bbe0b67fce1733443bfaddd52307e28fbe4e3c0945be31853d8f1caeb078dfc220
```

When change the value `71ef1c30a1a5503dd387aac85b714b779c7df8bc163b1fad66b1d51c94cd221e` with a new value `2C31FBB2B809A9B2252FE64EC6D0011A8EAAA4D0A72EEEDF0A1E1DCF1B514320` I get an error

```
$ printf 03d4f7e460787295bb803f7f9fa3c023b3cb33623aadbea53720decfa5a4f6005800000000 |xxd -r -p | openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac `printf 2C31FBB2B809A9B2252FE64EC6D0011A8EAAA4D0A72EEEDF0A1E1DCF1B514320 |xxd -r -p` | awk '{print $2}'
%/NЧ.: No such file or directory
C: No such file or directory
```

UPDATE
I tried with -macopt

first result is the same

```
$ printf 03d4f7e460787295bb803f7f9fa3c023b3cb33623aadbea53720decfa5a4f6005800000000 |xxd -r -p | openssl dgst -sha512 -mac HMAC -macopt key:`printf 71ef1c30a1a5503dd387aac85b714b779c7df8bc163b1fad66b1d51c94cd221e|xxd -r -p`   
(stdin)= 71af33b003e7e8033fcec8ad2ef46ee22b6518ae072fae24708201542d1b01bbe0b67fce1733443bfaddd52307e28fbe4e3c0945be31853d8f1caeb078dfc220
```

Second result same issue

```
$ printf 03d4f7e460787295bb803f7f9fa3c023b3cb33623aadbea53720decfa5a4f6005800000000 |xxd -r -p | openssl dgst -sha512 -mac HMAC -macopt key:`printf 2C31FBB2B809A9B2252FE64EC6D0011A8EAAA4D0A72EEEDF0A1E1DCF1B514320|xxd -r -p`   
??%/?N?????Ч.??: No such file or directory
?C: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It likely wrong to supply an arbitrary sequence of bytes as the argument of the -hmac option. The openssl documentation is not clear on what this key is supposed to be but for sure it is going to be parsed as a character string and processed after that, just like any other option to any command-line program.

Comment: thanks for the reply, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Try using `-mac hmac -macopt hexkey: 71ef1c30a1a5503dd387aac85b714b779c7df8bc163b1fad66b1d51c94cd221e`.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk with -macopt the result is different, Update my question

Comment: You can't create a command line containing arbitrary bytes, which you are still doing. To allow for specifying a key or any other value with arbitrary bytes something else must be done. openssl solves this problem by providing a `hexkey` option. You provide the key as **ASCII string containing hex digits** on the command line and, internally, openssl parses this into the desired bytes. Don't do `key:\`printf ABCD | xxd -r -p\``, that won't work. Instead, do `hexkey:ABCD`. No xxd -r output should be on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with double quotes

```
$ printf 03d4f7e460787295bb803f7f9fa3c023b3cb33623aadbea53720decfa5a4f6005800000000 |xxd -r -p | openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac "`printf 71ef1c30a1a5503dd387aac85b714b779c7df8bc163b1fad66b1d51c94cd221e|xxd -r -p`" | awk '{print $2}'
71af33b003e7e8033fcec8ad2ef46ee22b6518ae072fae24708201542d1b01bbe0b67fce1733443bfaddd52307e28fbe4e3c0945be31853d8f1caeb078dfc220

$ printf 03d4f7e460787295bb803f7f9fa3c023b3cb33623aadbea53720decfa5a4f6005800000000 |xxd -r -p | openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac "`printf 2C31FBB2B809A9B2252FE64EC6D0011A8EAAA4D0A72EEEDF0A1E1DCF1B514320 |xxd -r -p`" | awk '{print $2}'
3b63439866b95de9d5402688dd26162fdd25646262087bebdffe024c5136954ea34a8f908de1b523ebf3fa86813db6a098d153ac79a8905e520134799fec8247
```